# Laravel returning random Carbon Method Illuminate\\Support\\Carbon::getTimestamp does not exist error on ajax call

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, axios, php-carbon

New installation of Laravel - tried to reinstall and run composer update - same issue.

Laravel api project is returning randomly "Method Illuminate\Support\Carbon::getTimestamp does not exist." after ajax call from axios in separate vue.js client side project. This does not happen for every request. I will greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Carbon is a datetime package that would normally be referenced via \Carbon\Carbon. Maybe share your controller code for one of the requests that are failing?

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same problem, and simple "composer update" after some time should fix this, as Carbon breaks Laravel compatibility.